# Undefined variable: r Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Model

```
public function getDepartmentIdForName($id)
{

    $this->db->select("deptName,deptInfo");
    $this->db->from('departmentinfo');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        } 
     
}
```

> Controller

```
public function getDepartmentId($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Department_Model/Department_Model');
    
    $data['r'] = $this->Department_Model->getDepartmentIdForName($id,true);
    
    $data['r1'] = $this->Department_Model->getDepartmentImage($id,true);
    
     //redirect('admin/department' ,$data);
     $this->load->view('department' ,$data);
    
}
```

> view department

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
        
        <?php $this->load->model('Department_Model/Department_Model');?>
        <?php foreach($r->result() as $deName):?>
            <h4>
                    <?php echo $deName->deptName?>
            </h4>
            
          
          <p> <?php echo $deName->deptInfo?></p>
          <!-- Small Facts -->
       
        <?php endforeach ;?>
      
  </div><!---col-sm-9-->
```

Showing following error

> Undefined variable: r
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function result() on a non-object
>
> Filename: views/department.php
>
> Line Number: 35

Answer (score 1):

In model Change this

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $query->result_array();//here
}
```

In View

```
<?php foreach($r as $deName):?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit you controller:

```
public function getDepartmentId($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Department_Model');

    $data['r'] = $this->Department_Model->getDepartmentIdForName($id);

    $data['r1'] = $this->Department_Model->getDepartmentImage($id);

     //redirect('admin/department' ,$data);
     $this->load->view('department' ,$data);

}
```

And you don't need to load again model in view.

```
    <?php foreach($r->result() as $deName):?>
        <h4>
                <?php echo $deName->deptName?>
        </h4>


      <p> <?php echo $deName->deptInfo?></p>
      <!-- Small Facts -->

    <?php endforeach ;?>
```

as getDepartmentImage takes only 1 parameter.

Comment: you loaded model like: ('Department_Model/Department_Model'); change to ('Department_Model');

Answer (score 0):

In the model you are returning `$query->result()` and in the view you are also looping through `$r->result()` but `$r` is what you've return from the model. So you should use the `result()` method only on one of the places. Just remove `->result()` either from the model or from the view.